# Display Popup Message on Page Load with Cookie

Tags: php, jquery, cookies, popup, onload

I'm creating a popup message on my website with this tutorial: [LINK](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/htmlcss-tutorials/build-a-popup-modal-window-using-the-jquery-reveal-plugin/)

It's supposed to only display/popup, when the user is using IE7 or less, and only once - so I need to use cookies.

The tutorial uses a jQuery plugin called "Reveal" and is activated like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#button').click(function(e) {        // Button which will activate our modal
        $('#modal').reveal({                // The item which will be opened with reveal
            animation: 'fade',              // fade, fadeAndPop, none
            animationspeed: 600,            // how fast animtions are
            closeonbackgroundclick: true,   // if you click background will modal close?
            dismissmodalclass: 'close'      // the class of a button or element that will close an open modal
        });
    return false;
    });
});
```

The HTML that goes along with this script is written like so:

```
    <div id="modal">
        <div id="heading">
            Are you sure you want to do that?
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <p>Clicking yes will make Comic Sans your new system<br> default font. Seriously, have you thought this through?</p>
            <a href="#" class="button green close"><img src="images/tick.png">Yes, do it now!</a>
            <a href="#" class="button red close"><img src="images/cross.png">No, I’m insane!</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I tried adding the cookie myself to the `"Reveal"-plugin`, using [THIS](http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/svn-history/r6125/trunk/plugins/cookie/jquery.cookie.js) script, but with no luck:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        if ( $.cookie ( 'first_visit' ) !== '0' ){
            $('#modal').reveal({                // The item which will be opened with reveal
                animation: 'fade',              // fade, fadeAndPop, none
                animationspeed: 600,            // how fast animtions are
                closeonbackgroundclick: true,   // if you click background will modal close?
                dismissmodalclass: 'close'      // the class of a button or element that will close an open modal
            });
            $.cookie( 'first_visit' , '0' );
        return false;
        }
    });
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong? I want this popup message to display on IE7 and below - only on the first time visiting the site.

Comment: I don't see anything that should prevent other browsers than IE7- to view this. Does it show the message only once? For the browser issue, take a look at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/

Comment: It's not really the IE7 that's the problem - more the cookie registration.

Comment: [Doc may help ...](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/blob/master/README.md)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error on line 12 in script.js. You are using a method called `validationEngine`. Are you sure you loaded this, because I don't see it anywhere. You can also try to type `$.validationEngine` in your console, and it will tell you it is undefined. This will probably stop your javascript execution.

Either make sure you include this validation engine, or don't use it, and get back if the error is still there. From what I can see, your ussage of the cookie plugin is correct. It is also initialized, and I can use it on your site through the console.

**EDIT**

You are returning false after calling the modalizer initialization. I guess this is because you copied it from code that belongs to a click event on a html anchor (`<a />`), and it needs to stop the default action from being carried out (going to the link). I don't think it does anything in this case, but returning false on $.ready seems instintively like a pretty bad idea. Get rid of that!

Comment: now it pops up, but it does it every time i refresh the page. It seems like the cookie doesn't work? Can you answer that?

Comment: If you have skype or google+ or something, send me a mail (in my profile), so I can try in danish instead :P

Comment: Tror ikke, at jeg er høj nok rang til at sende beskeder ;)
- Bare tilføj `Fredegeek` på Skype :)

Answer (score 1):

if you want it to display on IE only use the IE Conditional Tags

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<script type="text/javascript">
... your code ...
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

[IE Conditional Comment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Also make a habit of testing your variable when debuging

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var cookie = $.cookie('first_visit');
        alert(cookie); // this will show you why it is not workin
        ....
```

Comment: Thanks - I was aware of that, though (sorry for not mentioning). I just need the cookie to work properly now.

Comment: @FrederickAndersen see my update, check what is the current value of cookie using `console.log()` or `alert()`